# Is there a way to start the Finder in the same folder when I am in the terminal?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

when operating, I always want to start the finder to the same folder as in the terminal.

Just like windows "start ." command

Is there a equivalent in Mac?

Comment: What do you mean by "when programming"? What application are you using, XCode?

Comment: changed, I am not mean programming always; but usually it is related to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to type this in your terminal?

```
open .
```

Comment: I think that's what I want :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
open .
```

The open command tells the gui to open any file as is it had been 2clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In `Finder -> Preferences -> General`, use the **New Finder windows open** menu to select the default window that's opened with <kbd>Cmd-N</kbd>.

You can also use <kbd>Cmd-H</kbd> to open your home folder, which is the default folder you're in when you open Terminal.